# Find the Tangent Plane (Undefined?)

Tags: functions

I've been asked to solve for a tangent plane at a point, but the method I'm using seems to lead to an answer that is undefined. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Write the equation of the tangent plane to the surface $x^2$+ $\frac{y^2}{4}$ +$z^2$ = $25$ at the point $(5, 0, 0)$.

The formula for when the expression is in the form $z = f(x,y)$ is:

$z-f(a,b)$ = $f_x$(a,b)$(x-a)$ + $f_y$(a,b)$(y-b)$.

Reworking the equation, I get $z = $ $\sqrt(25 - x^2 - y^2/4)$.

$f(x,y) = $ $\sqrt(25 - x^2 - y^2/4)$, therefore $f_x$ = $-x/\sqrt(25-x^2-y^2/4)$.

This means that $f_x(5,0)$ = $-x/\sqrt(25-5^2-0)$, or $-x/0$. Which is obviously undefined. So am I going wrong in here, or is the question supposed to have an undefined answer?

Comment: You are dealing with tangent plane problem in 3D thus you cannot choose any coordinate plane to be specific.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean by this, any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: I wrote a short answer below. Please have a look and I can explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perpendicular to the curve $f(x,y,z)=\hbox{constant}$ is given by
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)\ .$$
In this case,
$$\left(2x,\frac y2,2z\right)\ ,$$
and the point is $(5,0,0)$ so it's
$$(10,0,0)\ .$$
May as well say $(1,0,0)$ since that has the same direction, which is the only important thing.  So the plane has the form
$$x=d$$
and since it has to go through $(5,0,0)$,
$$x=5\ .$$

**Notice** that this plane cannot be written in the form $z=\langle\hbox{something}\rangle$, that's why your attempt failed.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I suppose the fact that it's undefined in that form is how I know that is not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

The usual procedure is to find the normal vector fisrt. In your case,

let $\vec{p}=(5,0,0)$,
$$\vec{n} = \nabla(x^2+y^2/4+z^2)|_p = (2x,y/2,2z)|_p = (10,0,0) $$

Then the tangent plane is given by $(\vec{x}-\vec{p})\cdot \vec{n}=0$ , where $\vec{x} = (x,y,z)$

Thus the tangent plane for your problem is 
$$ (x-5)*10=0 \Rightarrow x=5 $$

Comment: $(\vec{x} -\vec{p})\cdot \vec{n} = 0$ since any vector on the tangent plane is perpendicular to the normal vecgtor.